# Unit testing : 2 scenarios in one test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I want to know if I have a method to test :

```
public boolean validString(String str) {
   ...
}
```

Is is good to do a unit test like this :

```
public void should_valid_string() {
  assertTrue(validString("okString"));
  assertFalse(validString("wrongString"));
}
```

or it's better to do two tests ?

Comment: As long as you test all the different scenarios I don't think it's really important. Keep in mind that if you separate in two tests the `@Before` and `@After` are going to be executed before and after each test in case they are defined so it might matter in some scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this depends on how likely are your test cases fail all at once. In your example, if the first assert fails you don't know if the second one is ok. If you seperate them in two tests you get an atomic answer.